# Removable Media -Never prompt or start programs on media insertion- for all users

Tags: media, prompt

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop. I would like to know where (filename) the settings under All Settings-> Removable Media are stored. I would like to have the settings "Never prompt or start programs on media insertion apply to all my users with no option of changing by individual user.